# How to creat a background service for android developing

Tags: android

Hi I am new to android and it is also my first time I am going work with service which will work in the background. 
I mean I want to build a voice commanding application and I want it to listen the user's command even when it is closed. And I want to start my service at the time of pressing the 'Back' button by any user. 
I will be so grateful for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import android.app.Service;
```

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class Startappservice extends Service{

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.enwaye_connect.MainActivity");
    startActivity( LaunchIntent );
}
```

To start service on clicking back button:

```
Intent start= new Intent(this, Startappservice .class);
        startService(start);
```

Add in your manifest:

```
 <service android:name="your_package_name.Startappservice" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="our_package_name.Startappservice" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Sure. I'll check this out soon

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `Service` class. Create a class that derives from it and then you can add your methods to the service.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    // This is used to establish a communication with the service.
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }


    // Called when the service is created
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       // YOUR CODE
    }

    // Called when the service is started
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // YOUR CODE
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    // called when the service instance is destroyed
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
         // YOUR CODE
    }

    // Returns the binder which is used for communication with the service.
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }
}
```

To start the service use:

```
Intent start= new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(start);
```